# Normal Operators self adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

This is one of my homework questions and I was hoping someone could check my proof:

Prove that a normal operator with real eigenvalues is self-adjoint.

So what I thought to do was, for some normal operator $N$, we can write $$N=UDU^*.$$ So \begin{align}N^* &= (UDU)^* \\
&=(U^*)^* D^* U^* \\
&= UD^* U^*\end{align} We can say that $D^*= \overline{D}$, and since this is real, $D^* = D.$ So $$N^*=UDU^*.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Please do consider using $\LaTeX$ to typseset your questions. See the following link for a (rather extensive) outline on how to use the LaTeX environment (MathJax) on M.SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, assuming you're only considering finite dimensional spaces.

However, you should specify at the outset that $D$ is supposed to be diagonal, which is possible because any normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable.

You just have a typo in the line
$$
N^*=(UDU)^*
$$
which should be
$$
N^*=(UDU^*)^*
$$